# Custom TabBar navigation issues

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I implemented a custom tab bar controller as a set of buttons each one related to it's own View Controller. I guided on this link http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/04/how-does-the-twitter-iphone-app-implement-a-custom-tab-bar/ to achieve the behavior. So the relevant part of code is as follows:

```
- (void) selectedItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)itemIndex
{
// Get the right view controller
NSDictionary* data = [self.tabBarItems objectAtIndex:itemIndex];
UIViewController* viewController = [data objectForKey:@"viewController"];

// Remove the current view controller's view
UIView* currentView = [self.view viewWithTag:SELECTED_VIEW_CONTROLLER_TAG];
[currentView removeFromSuperview];


// Set the view controller's frame to account for the tab bar (+ 48)
viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,48,self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height - 48);

// Se the tag so we can find it later
viewController.view.tag = SELECTED_VIEW_CONTROLLER_TAG;

// Add the new view controller's view
[self.view insertSubview:viewController.view belowSubview:self.tabBar];

//Keep track of current view controller
self.currentController = viewController;
}
```

So far is working, I can see each view controller in a similar maner to the default TabBarViewController. But then there's a requirement where I need to push a new navigation controller modally (it should take all the application frame) from inside one of the tabBar controllers.

At first glance I tried the following code from within one of the tab controllers:

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController   alloc]init];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]detailViewController];
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

However is not working as expected, first the view is shown below the TabBar and second the new view is not taking in consideration the parent view frame which should be the screen bounds less the tabbar. (0, 48, 360, 412). My detail view controller it's loading content from a nib file.

Well, this is quite obvious since the TabBar Controller is inserting each view below my custom TabBar.

```
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

So I tried inserting it directly as a window subview:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

But, I think this is not okay... there should be a better approach that I can't figure out. So if anybody could give me suggestions on how to correct or improve this navigation system it would be great.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are building you app for iOS 5.0 and up you can make use of childViewController. In your custom Tab Bar you can have a containerView and a tabView.

The view of viewController is added to containerView. All the necessary events are generated to the subsequently added viewController if the following methods are implemented correctly

```
- (void)addChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childController;
- (void)removeFromParentViewController;
```

More about viewController containment can be found [here.](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/04/containing-viewcontrollers/)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I need to support 4.x devices.

Comment: If you have the privilege to take a decision, you can opt for minimum target of 5.0 as this makes view controller containment very easy.